# Calling a function from another form c#

Tags: c#

i have a main form with a function that changes the text of a text box thats on the main form, the code is below:

main form function:

```
    public void consoleLog(string message)
    {
        txtConsoleLog.Text += Environment.NewLine;
        txtConsoleLog.Text += message;
        txtConsoleLog.SelectionStart = txtConsoleLog.TextLength;
        txtConsoleLog.ScrollToCaret();
        txtConsoleLog.Refresh();
    }
```

So now i open a new form called frm connect when i click a button like this:

```
    private void connectToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form frmConnect = new FrmConnect(this);
        frmConnect.Show();
    }
```

this is the frmConnect below

```
public partial class FrmConnect : Form
{
    private Form mainForm;

    public FrmConnect(Form frmMain)
    {
        this.mainForm = frmMain;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FrmMain.Connected = true;
        mainForm.consoleLog("Connected");
    }
}
```

So when i click a button i want to call the function but its saying it doesnt contain a definition for it, also im trying to change the 'Connected' variable thats on the main form which works by just referencing the FrmMain but am i able to do that using mainForm.Connected = true?

If i change the function to public static, it will work by referencing FrmMain but then i get errors with the txtConsoleLog as i cant reference an object in a non static method or something like that, any help is appriciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change

```
private Form mainForm;

public FrmConnect(Form frmMain)
{
```

To

```
private FrmMain mainForm;

public FrmConnect(FrmMain frmMain)
{
```

which will later give you access to all of the public properties on `FrmMain` in your other methods in the `FrmConnect` class.

Comment: now its saying "Cannot implicity convert type system.windows.Forms.Form to Project1.FrmMain when i try to do this.mainForm = frmMain;

Comment: Are you sure you changed the type in both spots?

Answer (score 1):

When you pass the form into your constructor, and store it as the private member variable, in both places you declare it of the base type `Form`. In order to use a method on the type that you defined, your parameter and variable should be of type `FrmMain`.

```
public partial class FrmConnect : Form
{
    private FrmMain mainForm;

    public FrmConnect(FrmMain frmMain)
    {
        this.mainForm = frmMain;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FrmMain.Connected = true;
        mainForm.consoleLog("Connected");
    }
}
```

Comment: now its saying "Cannot implicity convert type system.windows.Forms.Form to Project1.FrmMain when i try to do this.mainForm = frmMain;

Comment: Change it in both spots like I did. Your `private Form mainForm;`